# Sharepoint: Modify/Reset site collection permissions for user when AD properties change

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I am not an expert with SharePoint and couldn't figure out if this questions has been answered already in SO. So, please redirect as necessary. Thanks!

Customer has a sharepoint farm (syncs with AD) which is a purely OOB implementation and no custom code. That said, the question is - if a user was updated in AD (a property of the user), can the user's permissions on the existing site collection, be modified/reset automatically without manual intervention?

Let's say if

- 1) User belongs to BusinessGroup "Group1" (AD) and the user has "Full
  Control" to SharePoint site collection "Group1-SiteColl".
- 2)   User's BusinessGroup is now changed to "Group2" in AD.

In this scenario, the user permissions on "Group1-SiteColl" should be reset to "ViewOnly" (or something of that sort) and the user should be given "FullControl" permission to the new SiteCollection "Group2-SiteColl"

How can this be achieved (automated, no manual intervention) without deploying any custom code. With PS or OOB workflows?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions only for users or groups (both SharePoint and AD). Based on AD properties you can define audiences to hide or display some parts (typically webparts) in SharePoint UI. But this is not equal to permissions!

Comment: Thanks Jan. Did  you mean "You can't set permissions" to begin with? You can hide/display parts but automatic permissions to site collections are not possible when AD properties change? Is that correct?

Comment: No, it is exactly as I wrote. You can set permissions to particular user or group identified by name. If you want use another property other then name to identify group you can define audience.